# Yii2 - Using Junction table with relations

Tags: yii2

I have a table **`Book`** and a table **`Cover`**. The relation between **`Book`** and **`Cover`** is `one-to-many`, meaning that each book can have more than one cover. I thus have a third table connecting the two, **`book-cover-relation`**.

Translating those to models means I have 3 models,

- **`Book`**,
- **`Cover`**,
- **`BookCoverRelation`**

Now In the **`Book`** model, I have the following relation for the related **`BookCoverRelations`**

```
public function getBookCoverRels() {
        return $this->hasMany(BookCoverRelation::className(), ['book' => 'id']);
    }
```

What I want though, is a to be able to get all the **`Covers`**. Is there way through which I can do this without first getting the relations and then iterating through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a relation with `viaTable` in `Books` Model

```
 public function getCovers(){
        return $this->hasMany( Covers::class,['id'=>'cover_id'])->viaTable('{{%book_cover_relation}}',['book_id'=>'id']);  
    }
```

and use it like

```
$qu = Books::findOne (['id'=>1]);

foreach($qu->covers as $cover){
    echo $cover->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [viaTable()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#viaTable()-detail) method to get all the **Cover** models "passing through" your **BookCoverRelations** junction table, as stated in the *Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0*: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#junction-table